# How to apply surf descriptor on the key features in opencv? ( mean and gaussian curvature)

Tags: opencv, 3d, svm, surf

I have taken a pcd file, extracted mean and gaussian curvature of every point  present in the 3D data.This acts as a key features. Now I have to apply SURF descriptor on it . Can you please guide me on how to use SURF descriptor on the features i have got.

Comment: opencv SURF descriptors are taken from 2d images (based on keypoint locations). do you have one ?

Comment: I want to apply it on 3D data - PCD file which has x,y and z points.

Comment: yes, that's what you want. but again, you need a 2d image, if you want to use opencv's SRF implementation.

Comment: I don't have 2d image, 
I have only pcd (point cloud data) file on which i have to perform feature extraction. 
Mean and Gaussian Curvature will be the key features and on these features, i want to apply descriptor.
Can you please suggest, what to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a 3D descriptor. SURF implementation in OpenCV only works in 2D.